# I cannot boot from CD/DVD/USB Stick

Tags: windows, bios

I cannot boot from CD/DVD in BIOS.

The only options that are shown two, both starting with "Ubuntu" and then the HDD name.

How can I change BIOS setting to boot from CD/DVD or USB DOK?

Comment: Please tell us as much as possible about your computer. It will help us help you.

Comment: I've got an Asus notebook, with an i5 3337U. The exact name is ASUS X452C notebook. If you need a specific detail, please ask me.

Comment: Yes it helps with more details, because the same brand name and model can have different hardware, for example graphics card/chip and wifi card/chip. How much RAM? I guess Windows is installed by the manufacturer in UEFI mode. You should turn off fast startup in Windows. Otherwise it is semi-hibernating, which prevents linux from seeing the partitions, which Windows is using on the internal drive.